# Understanding Java data types

Tags: java, types, byte, primitive

1) Why is the following assignment not allowed:

```
byte b = 0b11111111; // 8 bits or 1 byte
```

but this assignment is allowed:

```
int i = 0b11111111111111111111111111111111; //32 bits or 4 bytes
```

Both types are signed, and I would expect `b` and `i` were -1.

2) Why doesn't the Integer MIN_VALUE have a sign?

```
public static final int   MIN_VALUE = 0x80000000;
```

but the Byte MIN_VALUE does have a sign?

```
public static final byte   MIN_VALUE = -128;
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework assignments by an unmotivated student.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html .... you know... the document that explains all of this?

Comment: Actually, @NathanielWaggoner, that particular document doesn't explain either of these questions.

Comment: David is right; I just looked, and it doesn't say anything.  I'm also trying to figure out why `int i = 0b11..11` (with 32 1's) is legal but `int i = 4294967295` is not.  This is **not** a trivial question.  I'd suggest removing the close votes.

Comment: I applaud a student who actually asks questions about these basic nuts and bolts.  It shows that they are thinking, and wondering about things.  To label this person as "unmotivated" is unfair.

Comment: @rvillablanca: I don't think your question #2 is answerable.  The people who wrote the code had more than one way to write the constants, I think.  Asking this question is trying to read their minds.  It's just a style preference, I guess.

Comment: @ajb (in response to your first comment) it's because the leftmost 1 in 0b11...11 means -2^31, not +2^31.

Comment: You might also find it enlightening to know that `byte b = 0b11111111111111111111111111111111;` is compilable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All integer literals have type `int` (unless suffixed by an `L` or `l`).  Thus, in the first case, you're storing an `int` into a `byte`.  A narrowing conversion like this is not allowed without a cast, except that if the right side is a constant, it's allowed if the value is in range, which is `-128` to `127`.  `0b11111111` is 255, though, which is not in range.

As for why `int i = 0b11111111111111111111111111111111` is allowed: it's pretty much "because the JLS says so".  In fact, that specific example appears in [JLS 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).  There's a rule that *decimal* literals of type `int` cannot exceed 214743647 (except in the specific case `-2147483648`), but there's no rule about binary literals except that they have to fit into 32 bits.

As I mentioned in a comment, the second question is really a question about the style preference of the programmers who wrote the code, and it's impossible to answer.

Comment: @divanov I'll need to check because I think I've heard the verb "assign" used in both directions, but I've fixed it to avoid the word completely.

Comment: apparently I "fixed" it badly.  Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 6):

Question 1)

This is because `0b11111111` is an `int` literal, whose value is `255`.  This value doesn't fit into a byte.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html for more details on this.

Question 2)

When we write binary or hexadecimal literals, we never put a sign.  The literal `0x80000000` is actually a negative value, even though we don't write it as such.

There's no really good reason why the makers of the JDK chose to use a decimal literal for `-128` but a hexadecimal literal for `0x80000000`; except that in each case, it's probably a whole lot clearer that way what is intended.